# VOIP for Office

Tags: voip, phone-call, pbx

the scoop of this question 
we are operating virtually in USA (outsource) 
now we have 7 departments in our building here , and few dep in USA office

we want to make a setup that can connect our local office intercom with USA office 
i thing for this we will have pbx server and and there and connect both?
also if our sales department can call from there phone lines to USA landlines

what would be the good walkthrough for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. (Secure and reliable) I recommend yo to keep local PBX in the each office. As I understand, you need to have 2 PBXes - in the "our building here" and in the "USA office". And, write rules for route calls between PBXes, and if needed - route calls to landlines through SIP-provider. with this way, each phone system will work independently, and continue work local, even internet connection broken.
2. (Cheap) Another solution -- do not have PBX, and use accounts in the SIP-provider. Many SIP-providers allows free calls inside network, and you will call free by that network. Disadvantage of this solution -- your traffic goes over the world, and this is unsecure. Also, if provider's site out of service, or lost internet connection -- your system stop work.

Of course, you can use some combination of [1,2] - for example, keep PBX in your local office, and in US office use phone numbers from provider.

I can help you to install/setup FreeSWITCH PBXes, if needed, 
and connect to SIP-providers (not for free).
If you interesting, drop e-mail in comments.